# A simple question about VaR estimation

Tags: risk-management, value-at-risk, estimation, normal-distribution

"A 99% VaR using 1,000 (simulation) replications should be expected to have only
10 observations in the left tail, which is not a large number. The VaR estimate
is derived from the 10th and 11th sorted numbers. In contrast, a 95% VaR
is measured from the 15th and 51st sorted numbers, which is more precise"

Could anybody enlighten me why 95% VaR estimation uses the 15th data point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in your definition.  It should be between "50th and 51st" sorted numbers.  95% VAR means 5% is in the tail.  5% * 1000 = 50.  The 95% VAR will be the 50th worst outcome of your 1000 simulations.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. That matches what I think.

Comment: if a typo is the correct answer then vote